# Linking intel nasm x86_64 with C++ won't succeed

Tags: c++, assembly, nasm, extern

I am trying to make project in C++ with some calculations in assembly. Now I am trying to make asm function work within C++, but with no success.

```asm
;nasm_loop.asm

section .text

global asmfunc


asmfunc:
    push ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Makefile:

```make
OBJS = source.cpp

CC = g++

COMPILER_FLAGS = -w

LINKER_FLAGS = -lSDL2

OBJ_NAME = sdltest

all: nasm_test.o $(OBJS)
    nasm -f elf64 -o nasm_test.o nasm_test.asm
    $(CC) nasm_test.o $(OBJS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OBJ_NAME) 

nasm_test.o: nasm_test.asm
    nasm -f elf64 -o nasm_test.o nasm_test.asm



// source.cpp 
extern "C" void asmfunc();

int main()
{
    //...
    asmfunc();
    //...
}
```

and output:

```
lis@lis:~/Desktop/test2$ make
nasm -f elf64 -o nasm_test.o nasm_test.asm
g++ nasm_test.o source.cpp -w -lSDL2 -o sdltest 
/tmp/ccI33KiB.o: In function `main':
source.cpp:(.text+0x5bb): undefined reference to `asmfunc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

what am I doing wrong in here? What have I missed linking those files?

## SOLUTION

I just had to correct Makefile, thanks guys

```make
OBJS = source.cpp

CC = g++

COMPILER_FLAGS = -w

LINKER_FLAGS = -lSDL2

OBJ_NAME = sdltest

all: nasm_loop.o $(OBJS) 
    $(CC) nasm_loop.o $(OBJS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OBJ_NAME) 

nasm_loop.o: nasm_loop.asm
    nasm -f elf64 -o nasm_loop.o nasm_loop.asm
```

Comment: `push/pop ebp` is not encodable in 64-bit mode. NASM will fail assembling `nasm_test.asm`. Check that the assembling is actually taking place with the correct file and result.

Comment: Also your file says `nasm_loop.asm` but you link with `nasm_test.asm` instead. Which might explain why it assembles but doesn't link.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.